# Binding to a Dictionary<string, string> where the Key contains square brackets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am trying to bind items that belong to a Dictionary and it all works fine, until I run into KeyValuePairs where the Key contains square brackets. For example, imagine this contrived scenario:

```
model = new MyModel {
    MyDict = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "Apple[1]", "Green" }
    }
}
```

I then create a form as follows:

```
Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDict["Apple[1]"])
```

As expected, the field looks like this:

```
<input id="MyDict_Apple_1__" name="MyDict[Apple[1]]"> type="text" value="Green">
```

The problem is that when the form is submitted, the ModelBinder drops the last bracket: ModelBindingContext.ModelName is "MyDict[Apple[1]".

Is this a bug in the DefaultModelBinder, or am I missing something?

---

Update:

I found that there's a bug in how FormValueProvider reads keys from the data. Specifically, the bug is in the GetKeyFromEmptyPrefix method of [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.PrefixContainer](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/PrefixContainer.cs).

For now I'm working around the issue by using the old binding syntax, with separate fields for the Key and Value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MyDict[0].Key" value="Apple[1]" />
<input type="text" name="MyDict[0].Value" value="Green" />
```

Comment: No sure it could be called a bug since the `DefaultModelBinder` is designed to work with dictionaries using indexed collections with a `Key` and `Value` property - refer [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx). And as the article notes _if you don't like this behavior you're welcome to change it by writing your own binders for specific types or by pulling the information from a FormCollection_

Comment: Scott's article is from 2009. Model binding in newer versions of MVC supports dictionary binding where the key is inside the square brackets. This all works fine, except in cases where the key contains square brackets.

Comment: Yes, its basic support but its not what the `DefaultModelBinder` was designed for. Consider a `Dictionary<string, someComplexObject>` - if you were to use your technique of `@Html.EditorFor(m => model.MyDict[key])` it would generate `value="yourAssembly.someComplexObject"` and binding would fail. Use it as it was designed an all will work fine (or create your own model binder)

Comment: The use of Html.EditorFor was just to reinforce the fact that MVC supports this way of binding into a single field out of the box. I actually create the fields manually and I control how the data is encoded inside the value field.
In any case, I did start using the two-field method to work around the bug. Please see update to my original post.

Comment: Its not a bug! - its the way its designed to work! And you have referenced the asp.net-core-mvc method but tagged this just `asp.net-mvc (although the methods are the same)

Comment: And if it were to work the way you wanted it to, (by taking the index of the last closing `]`) then you would never be able to bind nested collections (e.g. `name="SomeProperty[0].AnotherProperty[0].Property value="xxx"`)